# Possible to collect data from a injectable service?

Tags: dependency-injection, webassembly

Scenario:

A blazor web assembly application that will manage, among other things, information about companies.

At login, I want the user to be able to select a "working company" and place it into an injectable service.  From that point on, when they open a page that provides details about a company, the injected service will contain the company that so that the user does not have to continue to select the company.

However, the user may not have originally intended to work with a specific company and, in this case, the service will not a select this company.

Is it possible to open a popup from an injectable service so that if the working company is requested but not selected, the user will be prompted to select one.

I want to place this in a service so that each page will not have to be aware of this logic.

Any suggestions on how to provide this functionality?